# Three set Venn diagram

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

> 2.14 A study of children 15 to 18 years of age in the United States considered the availability of various types of media in the child’s
> bedroom. It was found that 68% have a television, 92% have a CD/tape
> player, and 32% have a computer in their bedroom. Only 4% do not have
> a television, a CD/tape player, or a computer. Nine percent have a
> computer and a CD/tape player but no television. Forty- four percent
> have a television and a CD/tape player but no computer, and 1% have a
> television and a computer but no CD/tape player. A U.S. child, aged 15
> to 18, is selected, and whether or not the child has a television, a
> CD/tape player, or a computer in his or her room is observed. Express
> each of the following events in set notation and find the percentage
> of children, ages 15 to 18, represented by each.
>
> a The child has a
> television, CD/tape player, and computer in his or her bedroom.
>
> b The
> child has a television but no CD/tape player or computer in his or her
> bedroom.
>
> c The child has a CD/tape player but no television or
> computer in his or her bedroom.
>
> d The child has at least two of the
> media types (television, CD/tape player, computer) in his or her
> bedroom.

I understand that I need to solve this with a venn diagram. No biggie right? I Start popping numbers in and here is what I get:

[http://i.imgur.com/skzg5um.png](https://i.imgur.com/skzg5um.png)

However, I understand I have to start from the middle outwards. I attempted to use a system of equations to set the outer region of any of the circles to Y, set middle to x, subtrace the middle regions by X, solve for Y, and do substitution but this did not work for me. I do not want the answer. I am merely looking for a hint as to how to generate the center of a 3 set Venn Diagram without the outer regions and solely with the intersects. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this can be done by using the [Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). But let's solve it via a system of equations instead. Define:

- $a = \text{Pr}(A \cap \overline B \cap \overline C)$
- $b = \text{Pr}(\overline A \cap  B \cap \overline C)$
- $c = \text{Pr}(\overline  A \cap \overline B \cap C)$

Then we know that:
\begin{align*}
x + 0.44 + 0.01 + a &= 0.68 \\
x + 0.44 + 0.09 + b &= 0.92 \\
x + 0.09 + 0.01 + c &= 0.32 \\
x + 0.44 + 0.01 + 0.09 + a + b + c + 0.04 &= 1 \\
\end{align*}
Combine the first $3$ equations:
\begin{align*}
3x + 2(0.44 + 0.01 + 0.09) + (a + b + c) &= (0.68 + 0.92 + 0.32) \\
x + (0.44 + 0.01 + 0.09) + (a + b + c) + 0.04 &= 1 \\
\end{align*}
Subtract the two equations:
$$
2x + (0.44 + 0.01 + 0.09) - 0.04 = (0.68 + 0.92 + 0.32) - 1
$$
Solve for $x$:
$$
x = \frac{(0.68 + 0.92 + 0.32) - 1 - (0.44 + 0.01 + 0.09) + 0.04}{2} = 0.21
$$